# How can i extend the root directory of Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, 16.04, gparted, root

[image: This is my partitions]

/dev/sdb14 is my root directory , i want to extend size of it from /dev/sdb16. As partitioning is very sensitive issue . I don't want to make any mistakes. I know there are lot of existing answers exist in here. But it would be really helpful if someone tells me specifically .

Comment: That would be easy with [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux))… Can you use another drive to store current `/dev/sdb14` contents and convert `/dev/sdb14` to a logical volume? BTW, *why* so many partitions?!

Comment: The others are for windows . My brother uses those . I have no idea about those .

Comment: @Melebius /dev/sdb14 is root directory .if i move the contests to other directory isn't it gonna harm the whole partition ?

Comment: Well, it must be done very carefully… There is an alternative: You could mount `/dev/sdb16` somewhere in your Linux filesystem. Would you be OK with a single location (for example `/home/user/misc`, `/var/www/html` or even `/media/datadisk`) not extending available root space? Something similar to what your brother has probably done already with all those NTFS partitions… Another question: Do you want to keep the data in `/dev/sdb16` or could it be formatted?